# Single quoted string for sed in Makefile

Tags: makefile, sed

I am calling `sed` from my `Makefile`, and this line doesn't work:

```
sed -i -r 's|^(3)$|5|' file;
```

It's perfectly fine if I call from the terminal, but GNU make reports the following error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 8:
>   unterminated `s' command

Any ideas how I can fix this, and could you provide any manual on how Makefile deals with strings? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$` has a special meaning in makefiles. Use `$$` cancel it:

```
sed -i -r 's|^(3)$$|5|' file;
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem for me. Are there some manuals I can follow with the special characters in Makefiles, and the procedure that `make` process the strings?

Comment: @Ryan Nice to help you. [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).